TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
I am new to vue.js and i'm trying to upgrade a relatively big vue 2 project to vue 3 and after i updated all the necessary files, i came across this TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' error in the development server. I couldn't find anything that solves my problem.
I think the problem is something to do with the router.js and i am really not sure.
Here is the exact error message:
runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:180 Uncaught (in promise) 
TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at insert (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:180:12)
    at move (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5726:7)
    at move (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5681:7)
    at move (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5695:9)
    at move (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5695:9)
    at Object.resolve (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1680:11)
    at mountSuspense (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1426:14)
    at Object.process (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1341:7)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4614:16)
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4831:7)


Without the way to reproduce the problem, it needs to be isolated on your side. This could be faulty logic in component templates, or incompatible libraries, or anything else. Either disable parts of the app until the error doesn't happen, or set a breakpoint at runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:180:12 and track when and why parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' (it's probably null), or both. Since nothing is known about your project, nothing else can be suggested
